# User Fields pending Admin Approval?

Tags: entities, users

I'm putting together a public facing site with not always mature users, and I'm wondering if there is an off the shelf module for **requiring admin approval to user field submissions/changes**?

I.e. so that one of our staff get a notification when a user updates some selected settings (My Biography, that kind of thing) and it sits, pending review, before it goes public?

I'm trying to avoid the inevitable genital-graffiti that I know this lot are very capable of...

Answer (score 1):

I set up a workflow for doing this using [field permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions), [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules), and [revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning).  It works at the node level rather than the field level though, and it's rather complicated to set up.  In my searching there was no single module able to handle this.

Basically, I used rules to create a workflow in which users can only create and edit certain content types, all of which are subject to approval either upon creation or edit (using revisioning).